# Why is hostapd echoing and forwarding frames?

Tags: network-programming, hostapd

In a nutshell: hostapd v1.1 appears to be both echoing an altered version management frames back onto its input interface and forwarding the original frame to its output interface.

Our system is using libtins to send all management frames appearing on eth1 to a monitor interface for hostapd, mon.wlan0. We see that these frames are only forwarded to mon.wlan0 by libtins once, but a duplicate frame also arrives at mon.wlan0, with the only change being a monidification. In addition, these management frames are somehow being forwarded to hwsim0, hostapd's output interface. Why would this be occurring and how can it be stopped?

There isn't a wealth of information on hostapd functionality, but I was under the impression that frames simply arrive at hostapd and die there, without any forwarding or echoing.